# Why does package naming in java has TLD in the beginning

Tags: java

Why does java recommend having TLD in the beginning of the package names i.e., why does it have to be

```
package com.example.pack;
```

It can as well be

```
package pack.example.com;
```

Just wondering what might be the reason behind deciding to put the TLD in the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package correspond to directories in the file system. pack.example.com and pack.example2.net would both be in the same directory, even if the url suggest they are not related, but with com.example.pack and net.example2.pack, related packages are in the same directory.

Answer (score 3):

This convention is documented [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), it is proven and works for quite a lot of things.

The universe is `com` and can be `SG`, `ORG` or any TLD :).

Followed by your domain `example`.

Followed by your project `pack`.

Followed by your layer `web | ejb | data`.

```
com.example.pack.web
com.example.pack.ejb
com.example.pack.data
com.example.project2.web
com.example.project2.ejb
com.example.project2.data
com.singtel.projecta.web
com.singtel.projectb.data
```

Comment: I'd upvote apart form the `The universe is com` sentence, there are plenty of other commonly used top level package names.  e.g. org or net

Answer (score 0):

It's just the common convention to go from the more general to the more specific, and not vice versa.

In the same vein, we write:

- `package_name`.`class_name` (and not `class_name`.`package_name`);
- `object`.`member`;
- `outer_class`.`inner_class`;

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Java package name should always read from least specific to most specific. 
Therefore it should always start with domain name first.

Answer (score 0):

One good reason for it is that the classname is **prefixed** rather than **suffixed** with the package name --  so you're moving in the same direction after each dot. Also, package names map to directory names, which also force the broadest-first order.

Answer (score 0):

In a tree, the trunk is the main part the leaf is the less general part.

A package name is a tree.

Think of a class search in all classes in your classpath for one written by you. You would start com.* com.example.* etc, etc. Till you find your one.

Answer (score 0):

The main motive is to avoid namespace collisions by organizing classes and resources hierarchically, like a filesystem. It would be awkward referencing a text file as `MyDoc.txt\My Documents\C:`. Using your TLD name, reversed, organizes things more naturally from more general to more specific.